# How to make chart slide along X-axis in achartEngine by not showing the graph outside y axis

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working on the aChartEngine and plotting a bar chart. The chart i have been able to plot successfully but as i need to plot the values on the X-axis dynaimcally so i made the graph scrollable on the x-axis but when I am scrolling the chart on the X-axis, The bar chart are crossing the Y-axis and some part are visisble outside Y-Axis also.

I think the picture will give an broad idea what i meant to say.
 [image]

In the Above image I have set scrolling on X-axis as true but when i scroll the bar chart on X-axis some of the part of bar chart is crossing Y-Axis . I want as soon as it touches the Y-axis the bar should not be visible. 
I tried many options but getting no Idea.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private View mChart;
    private String[] mMonth = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_sample_chart);
        openChart();
    }
    private void openChart(){
        int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
        int[] income = { 2000,2500,2700,3000,2800,3500,3700,3800, 0,0,0,0};
        // Creating an XYSeries for Income
        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            incomeSeries.add(i,income[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.CYAN); //color of the graph set to cyan
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);

        multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridY(false);
        multiRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(4000);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1.0);

        LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        mChart = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(ChartMainActivity.this, dataset, multiRenderer,Type.DEFAULT);
        chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}
}
```